# Confusion between "int array[int]" and "int *array"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

```
int array[100];

int *array;
```

I am confused about the differences between `int array[100]` and `int *array`.

Essentially, when I do `int array[100]` (`100` it's just an example of an `int`), I just reserved space in memory for 100 ints, but I can do `int * array` and I didn't specify any type of size for this array, but I can still do `array[9999] = 30` and that will still make sense.

So what's the difference between these two?

Comment: *"i didn't specify any type of size for this array"* You have to though, usually doing something in the vein of `int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10000)`, here the `10000` is the size. If you don't make your pointer point to valid memory,  then `array[9999]=30;` is undefined behavior and will likely crash your program or cause other wrong/unpredictable results.

Comment: for starters, `int *array` has to be malloc()-ed manually.

Comment: ohh thx very much

Comment: I suggest sections 4, 5, 6, and 7 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: @JoaoParente: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pointer is a *pointer*, it points somewhere else (like the first element of an array). The compiler doesn't have any information about where it might point or the size of the data it might point to.

An array is, well, an array of a number of consecutive elements of the same type. The compiler knows its size, since it's always specified (although sometimes the size is only implicitly specified).

An array can be initialized, but not assigned to. Arrays also often decay to pointers to their first element.

Array decay example:

```
int array[10];

int *pointer = array;  // Here the symbol array decays to the expression &array[0]

// Now the variable pointer is pointing to the first element of array
```

Arrays can't naturally be passed to function. When you declare a function argument like `int arr[]`, the compiler will be translating it as `int *arr`.

All of this information, and more, should be in any good book, tutorial or class.

Comment: The compiler does not always know the size of an array. For example `extern int array[];` declares an array defined in a different mdule or merely later in the same module. The size is unknown and `sizeof(array)` should produce an error.

Answer (score 3):

A non-technical explanation:

A pointer's *contents* refer to an address (which may or may not be valid).  An array *has* an address (which must be valid for the array to exist).

You can think of a pointer as being like an envelope - you can put any address you want on it, but if you want it sent to somewhere in particular, that address has to be correct.

An array is like your house - it exists somewhere, so it *has* an address.  Things properly addressed get sent there.

In short:

**A pointer *holds* an address.**

**An array *has* an address.**

So

```
int *array;
```

creates a pointer *of indeterminate value* (it can point anywhere!).

When you then have

```
array[9999] = 30;
```

you're trying to set the 9999th `int` value **from where `array` points** to the value of 30.  But you don't know where `array` points because you didn't give it an actual value.

And that's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is when you do `int array[100]`, a memory block of `100 * sizeof(int)` is allocated on the *stack*, but when you do `int *array`, you need to dynamically allocate memory (with `malloc` function for example) to use the `array` variable. Dynamically allocated memory is on the *heap*, not *stack*.

Comment: The question does not show whether these declarations appear inside or outside a function, which affect how memory is allocated. And how memory is provided is implementation-dependent. Also, it is not required to dynamically allocate memory to use a pointer. The pointer could be set to point to other memory, such as inside another array.

Answer (score 2):

`int array[100]` means a variable `array` which will be able to hold 100 int values this memory will be allocated from the stack. The variable`array` will be having the base address of the array and memory will be allocated for the same.

But in the case of `int *array` since you are declaring this as a local variable, pointer variable `array` will be having a garbage address. So if you do `array[9999]` it could cause a segmentation violation since you are trying to access garbage memory location outside your program.

Comment: Accessing `array[9999]` will not always cause a segment violation. The behavior is not defined by the C standard. The address may be inside accessible memory, or the code may be transformed in unexpected ways by optimization.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But in most cases a crash will occour.

Comment: The answer could say accessing an array out of bounds often causes a segment violation, but it should not lead the reader to believe they may expect that behavior. Answers should contain true statements and should not contain false statements.

Comment: >typedef  struct edge{int dest ;int cost ;struct edge ∗next ;} ∗EList ;
>typedef EList Graph[100] 
so if i had something like these i could do :
EList hash; hash[30]=NULL, cuz by declaring on type the size of it when i declare EList hash it will create an hash table of size 100 automatically right?

Comment: @AmalJohn most of the cases I've dealt with uninitalized pointers i've ended up with a pointer to `main` that can be read but not written

Answer (score 1):

Some points that you can find useful to know:

- Via `int arr[N]` you specify **an array** of type `int` which can store `N`
  integers. To get information about how much memory array is taking you can use `sizeof` operator. Just multiply the number of items in an array by the size of type: `N*sizeof(int)`.
- Name of the array points to the first element in an array, e.g. `*arr` is the same as `arr[0]`, also you may wonder why [a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a).
- An uninitialized array of non-static storage duration is filled with indeterminate values.
- The size of an array may be known at runtime, if you write `int arr[] = {1, 2}` the size is calculated by a compiler.
- Accessing an unexisting element can cause **undefined behaivor**, which means that anything could happen, and in most cases you'll get garbage values.

---

- Via `int *array` you specify **a pointer** `array` of type `int`
- Unless a value is assigned, a pointer will point to some garbage address by default.
- If you don't allocate memory at all or not fully allocate it or access unexisting element but try to use a pointer as an array, you'll get undefined behavior as expected.
- After allocating memory (when the pointer is no longer needed) memory should be freed.

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying size in `int * array`, `array[9999] = 30` can cause segmentation fault as it may lead to accessing of inaccessible memory

Basically `int * array` points to a random location. For accessing the 9999th element the `array` must point to a location having that much sufficient space. But the statement `int * array` doesn't explicitly creates any space for that.

Answer (score 0):

`int array[100];` defines an **array** of `int`.

`int *array;` defines a **pointer** to an `int`. This pointer may point to an `int` variable or to an element of an array of `int`, or to nothing at all (`NULL`), or even to an arbitrary, valid or invalid address in memory, which is the case when it is an uninitialized local variable. It is a tad misleading to call this pointer `array`, but commonly used when naming a function argument that indeed points to an actual array. The compiler cannot determine the size of the array, if any, from the pointer value.

Here is a topographic metaphor:

- Think of an array as a street with buildings. It has GPS coordinates (memory address) a name (but not always) and a fixed number of buildings (at a given time, hard to change). The street name together with the building number specifies a precise building. If you specify a number larger than the last number, it is an invalid address.
- A pointer is a very different thing: think of it as a an address label. It is a small piece of paper that can be used to identify a building. If it is blank (a null pointer), it is useless and if you stick it to a letter and send that, the letter will get lost and discarded (undefined behavior, but it is easy to tell that it is invalid). If you write an invalid address on it, the effect is similar, but might cost much more before failing delivery (undefined behavior and difficult to test for).
- If a street is razed (if memory was freed), previously written address labels are not modified, but they no longer point the anything useful (undefined behavior if you send the letter, the difficult kind). If a new street is later named with the name on the label, the letter might get delivered, but probably not as intended (undefined behavior again, memory was freed and some other allocated object happens to be at the same memory address).
- If you *pass* a building to a function, you would usually not unearth it and truck it, but merely pass its street address (a pointer to the n-th building of the street, `&array[n]`). If you don't specify a building and just name the street, it means go to the beginning of the street. Similarly, when passing an array to a function is C, the function receives a pointer to the beginning of the array, we say that *arrays decays as pointers*.